# HREF from a JSON String?

Tags: html, json, href

Can't seem to get the link to work correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's my code so far:

**HTML:**

```
<section class="page2">
     <div class="page_container">
        <h1> <a class="text-btn2" href="link1"> <div id="title1"></div> </a>
        </h1>
     </div>
</section>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
  $.getJSON(
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/politics/top/.json?",
    function foo(data) {
      $.each(
        data.data.children.slice(0, 2),
        function (i, post) {
      $('#title' + i).append(post.data.title + '<p>');
      $('#link' + i).append(post.data.url + '<p>');
        }
      )
    }
  )
</script>
```

Any thoughts? Maybe I have my format wrong on the href?
Webpage shows this when I click on a link:
Error response

Error code 404.

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.